# jmeter unique id per thread for http request

Tags: jmeter

My jmeter tests make a http request which contains a unique id.

```
http://myserver.com/{uniqueId}/
```

I want to set the base number (say 35000) and increment for each thread, for example my ids would be 35001, 35002, 35003 ...

```
http://myserver.com/{base + count}
```

I see functions for __threadnum and __counter but how would I:

1. set it in a variable so that I can substitute it in my url
2. add this count to my base value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would simply go with Beanshell pre processor.

```
int threadNo = ctx.getThreadNum()+1; //to get the thread number in beanshell
int base = 35000;
int uniqueId = threadNo + base;
vars.put("uniqueId", Integer.toString(uniqueId));
```

Now your HTTP requests as given below should have the value substituted.

http://myserver.com/${uniqueId}/

Comment: I expanded upon this and added the Beanshell preprocessor to my first http request and use the variables throughout my test.  Perfect example!

Answer (score 2):

To set a variable per thread you can use [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables).

To sum, you can use functions:

- [__intSum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)
- [__longSum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum)

Or use a [JSR223 PRE Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) or [JSR223 POST Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) + Groovy and do it in Groovy.