# Jmeter: Is it possible to increment the value of variable for every thread in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Example: 
Thread: 50,
Ramp-Period: 0, 
Loop: 1.

I have to send different value with each thread. Is it possible to do it without changing the loop count?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need to add something to an existing variable it may be done via [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function
2. [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function generates incremented number each time it's being called either per-thread or global
3. Another candidate is [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function which is basically the number of current thread.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for advanced information on above and other useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like this - [jmeter unique id per thread for http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614232/jmeter-unique-id-per-thread-for-http-request)

You can also use `Beanshell` to create an unique ID for every thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a counter under the thread group.
In the counter it's possible to set the start, increase and maximum number you want to reach.
Then add reference name in counter, which will be used in your request as ${reference_name}